# Does pointwise convergence to a continuous function in compact set imply uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $K$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$, $f_n$ is a sequence of functions such that $f_n$ converges pointwise to a continuous function $f$, does it imply $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $K$ ?

**Edit:**
(addition of Hypothesis)$f_n$ is continuous for each $n$

If it is not true, what example justifies it ?

Comment: I believe this is the statement of Dini’s Theorem. In that case, yes.

Comment: @FedePoncio I believe Dini's Theorem has a monotonicity assumption

Comment: Actually, Dini requires $f_n$ to be either increasing or decreasing. Without that condition I don’t think it holds

Comment: @angryavian Yes, thank you

Comment: Yes..the sequence must be monotone sequence of functions. But what if monotonicity is omitted ?

Comment: You can't omit anything from Dini's theorem.

Comment: Lokk [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-around-dini-s-theorem/) for various counterexamples showing all hypotheses of Dini's theorem are necessary.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you

Comment: @Mark Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if there is no condition that $f_n$ are continuous. Counterexample: $K = [0,1]$, $f_n(x)$ $=$ $0$ for $x\neq1/n$, $1$ for $x = 1/n$, $f(x) \equiv 0$.

EDIT: For continuous functions it is still not true. $K$ and $f$ as above, and $f_n(x) = 0$ for x < $1/2n$, $0$ for $x > 3/2n$, $1$ for $1/n$ and linear on intervals $[1/2n,1/n]$ and $[1/n,3/2n]$.

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I missed to mention that $f_n$'s are continuous.

Comment: Thank you. That example works.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = [0, 2]$ and $$f_n(x) =\begin{cases}
n^2x^2 − 2nx, 0 \leq x \leq 2/n\\
0,&2/n\lt x \leq 2\\
\end{cases}$$

Clearly  $f_n $ is continuous and converges pointwise to $0$, but the convergence is not uniform.